# Moving email accounts between shared-hosting servers

Tags: email, shared-hosting

I've got to move email from one shared-hosting server to another.

The reason to move is my current provider doesn't support IMAP, so access to emails is only through POP.

I have 5 accounts to move, with 3 of them being > 500MB. Is there a way to do it? (other than downloading it all to a client and updating server settings to new server and therefore uploading the files to new server)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've already said that the only connection mechanism you have is POP so that's all that there is going to be available. There are some tools out there built to do bulk POP migrations of data when you have a ton of mailboxes involved to reduce the manual work but with just 5 accounts, it probably wouldn't save you much time.

The only other obvious solution is to see if the current company is willing to dump the data to DVDs or something for you. Some hosters will do this for a fee.

Comment: FYI it took me about 18hrs to migrate 6 email accounts, total 2.3GB, but it was mostly due to slow upload speed.